# Extract SRC of IMG with specific ID in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I know that this question has been posted a lot of times and I read through all the previous questions. I could not find a way to make this work.

I need to extract the src url of an img tag with a particular id. Input format is -

```
<img class"image" id="prdImage" width="277" height="400" alt="someimage" src="http://url/image.jpg"/>
```

src attribute is always the last, class is always the first. Also, this code will be in a large HTML document. I only gave the relevant part.

What I have till now-

```
/<img class="image" id="prdImage".+?src="(.+?)".+?\/>/i
```

This is working fine except that it is returning the entire img tag instead of only the src attribute;

*Note: I know that I should use a DOM parser for such cases. But for this project, I can only use regular expressions.*

Comment: Figured it out. I match the string in between the id and src attributes also in the regex expression. In this way, I get the src url in the second element of the results array rather than the first element.

Comment: if you had figured out the answer,just post your answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself. Here is the expression

```
/<img class="image" id="prdImage"(.*?)src="(.*?)"\/>/i
```

This will return an array with the url in the second position.

I am accepting this answer since I figured it out myself. If anybody else has a better solution, I will accept their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(?<=<img.*?src=")(.*?)(?="/>)
```

That regex will return

```
http://url/image.jpg
```

from your input string

```
<img class"image" id="prdImage" width="277" height="400" alt="someimage" src="http://url/image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: This will match for an image tag with any id/class. I wanted to match only for specific id/class. Upvote for trying though!

Comment: You cant take few parts of string as one part, using regex. To do this, take every part you want, and then concat their.